# VPN connection is not working properly after installing 12.04

Tags: 12.04, vpn

I've done a clean install of Ubuntu Precise.
I'm living in a country in which my access to many websites are restricted and I usually use VPN connections to access these websites. I use the default gnome-network applet for this purpose and my connection type is pptp.
Everything was ok until I installed Ubuntu 12.04. Now after creating the VPN connection I can get it connected but the problem is, it's like it's not there at all. I can access the unrestricted websites easily but when it comes to restricted websites I can't get through!
I [checked my IP](http://www.cmyip.com) and it's changed accordingly.
The VPN server is ok as I checked it on Windows. I wonder what is the problem here?

Comment: I don't know why but my problem resolved by itself, so I can't put further details in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same. Solved after installing network-manager-vpnc I *guess*, which for some reason was removed with the upgrade.

Comment: I have the same problem, also after upgrading, not a clean install. Network-manager-vpnc was not removed with the upgrade and is still installed. Connection type is cisco udp in my case.